# Forestall duplicated columns when add TypeDescriptor Provider's

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource, system.componentmodel

I'm trying to add a TypeDescriptor Provider for a class that I use how datasource in my datagridview, with this code:

```
private void FrmTarifadoVariantes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddProvider((new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<TarifadoVarianteBE>()), typeof(TarifadoBloquesBE));
        System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddProvider((new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<BloquePrendaBE>()), typeof(TarifadoBloquesBE));
    }
```

> QUESTION 1:

First time all is good, but when I closed the form and open again, the data provider descriptor **twice columns**, I tried to remove first the providers and then add again, but It doesn't work.

There is MyTypeDescriptionProvider, that I found searching on web:

```
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider<T> : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private ICustomTypeDescriptor td;
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : this(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(TarifadoBloquesBE)))
    {
    }
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider parent)
        : base(parent)
    {
    }
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        if (td == null)
        {
            td = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
            td = new MyCustomTypeDescriptor(td, typeof(T));
        }
        return td;
    }
}

public class SubPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private PropertyDescriptor _subPD;
    private PropertyDescriptor _parentPD;

    public SubPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor parentPD, PropertyDescriptor subPD, string pdname)
        : base(pdname, null)
    {
        _subPD = subPD;
        _parentPD = parentPD;
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return _parentPD.ComponentType; }
    }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return _subPD.PropertyType; } }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return _subPD.GetValue(_parentPD.GetValue(component));
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        _subPD.SetValue(_parentPD.GetValue(component), value);
        OnValueChanged(component, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class MyCustomTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    Type typeProperty;
    public MyCustomTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent, Type type)
        : base(parent)
    {
        typeProperty = type;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection cols = base.GetProperties(attributes);


        string propertyName = "";
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor col in cols)
        {
            //se agregó si el attributo es browsable
            if (col.IsBrowsable)
            {
                if (col.PropertyType.Name == typeProperty.Name)
                {
                    propertyName = col.Name;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        PropertyDescriptor pd = cols[propertyName];
        PropertyDescriptorCollection children = pd.GetChildProperties();
        PropertyDescriptor[] array = new PropertyDescriptor[cols.Count + children.Count];
        int count = cols.Count;
        cols.CopyTo(array, 0);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor cpd in children)
        {
            if (cpd.IsBrowsable)
            {
                array[count] = new SubPropertyDescriptor(pd, cpd, pd.Name + "_" + cpd.Name);
                count++;
            }
        }

        //PropertyDescriptor[] arrayTmp = new PropertyDescriptor[count];

        Array.Resize(ref array, count);

        PropertyDescriptorCollection newcols = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(array);
        return newcols;
    }
}
```

> QUESTION 2:

How can I make MyTypeDescriptionProvider dinamyc, I mean if you can check, I hard code the class (TarifadoBloquesBE) of the GetProvider, in this part:

```
private ICustomTypeDescriptor td;
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : this(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(TarifadoBloquesBE)))
    {
    }
```

I want to allow sending what class will be the provider. Thank you.

I attached two images, first one is ok, the next one you can check twice columns, just seeing the scroll bar.

**All good here**

[image: All good]

**Duplicate columns**

[image: Duplicate columns]